# Why am I receiving HTTP GETs for a domain I don't own?

Tags: http, apache, dns-domain, log-analysis

I am running a `Centos7` web server. I noticed a few strange HTTP `GET` requests like these:

```
94.185.83.100 - - [29/Feb/2016:23:29:00 +0530] "GET http://testp1.piwo.pila.pl/testproxy.php HTTP/1.1" 404 390 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
185.25.151.159 - - [01/Mar/2016:07:36:40 +0530] "GET http://testp1.piwo.pila.pl/testproxy.php HTTP/1.1" 404 390 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
```

1. I have no connection to the domain `piwo.pila.pl`. How did it end up in my Apache `access_log`?
2. In the `error_log` document, the same document is given under my web root, i.e.: `[Mon Feb 29 23:29:00.175813 2016] [:error] [pid 11382] [client 94.185.83.100:43718] script 'myWebRoot/testproxy.php' not found or unable to stat`
   Is this expected behavior? That the `access_log` keeps a record of the exact request while the `error_log` tracks the same request but translated to a URL on the file system?

Comment: I asked a very similar question [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/84720/external-websites-in-logs). The answer really helped me to understand why this happens and how it works.

Comment: @ZacharyDow: Thank you for that link. That was helpful.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your website has been hit by an automated script that looks for open proxies on the internet. The url it's trying to access would record a successful proxied request and add your server to a list.

Comment: thank you for your reply. but how does a request to piwo.pila end up on my server? How and where has that "mapping" been done? Also, is the error_log path correct, I mean is that how it is supposed to look?

Comment: Anyone can connect to a web server and request any host at all. It's like asking why someone calls your phone number and asks for the wrong person.

Comment: @wireghoul: thanks. Your answer and the other links helped out quite a bit.