# Unknown website tries to connect to my website

Tags: web-application, malware, attacks, webserver

A few minutes ago an error popped up on my error tracing app. I'm hosting a Django app which has login system. 
The error says:

> Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'www.moxing.one'. You may need to add 'www.moxing.one' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

```
status_code: 400
"<WSGIRequest: GET '/forum.php'>"
```

From IP address: `70.39.117.18`

I've found that IP address on some blocklist from FireHol [link to blocklist](https://github.com/firehol/blocklist-ipsets/blob/master/nullsecure.ipset)

And also the `www.moxing.one` refers to some chinese forums.

My question is should I be worried? What's the purpose of these "attacks"? I opened the `www.moxing.one`. Can it do some harm even if I immediately closed the page?

Comment: All I can say is, "Welcome to the Internet". You will get thousands of these types of things from all over the world. Visiting the site is another matter and we cannot begin to speculate what might happen if you visit this one site.

Comment: Actually I think the sites linked as duplicates are wrong, it is more likely to be proxy scanning, see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/116504/why-am-i-receiving-http-gets-for-a-domain-i-dont-own/116505#116505 for details

Comment: @wireghoul Sounds more accurate. Thanks!